# MigraDoc to display RichText String

Tags: c#, richtext, migradoc

I am converting our current PDF export using ITextSharp over to Migradoc. We currently render Rich Text to ITextSharp from a string stored in the database - for example:

```
<p><strong style=\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\"><u>test</u></strong></p>
```

ITextSharp is able to pick out the elements of this and render appropriately using (I think) `Cell.AddElement(ElementListItem)`.

Ideally I am looking for something identical to this for MigraDoc but any help on RTF in MigraDoc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc does not parse HTML.

You can use the `AddFormattedText` method of the `Paragraph` class to mix various rich formats within one paragraph, but parsing the HTML is up to you.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx